# FileNotFoundException is not getting catched or thrown

Tags: java, printing, path, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

It's happening with 2 different methods, it both cases the EDT (swing components) blocks and can't do anything.

In the first I'm trying with **throws** , it sends strings to a printer, so the FileNotFoundException is because the printer is not being found (and that's not a problem, I know the printer is not connected.).

```
public void methodOne ()  throws PrintException, FileNotFoundException{
...
//a lot of lines
...
//not working code:
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
Doc doc=new SimpleDoc(bytes,flavor,null);
//and here is where the exception should be thrown:
pj.print(doc, null);

}
```

In the second method I'm using **try catch**, it sends a String to a printer too.

```
public void methodTwo(){
String code2 = "1B700096FA";//hex
FileOutputStream os = null;
PrintStream ps=null;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream("LPT1:POS-58");
    ps= new PrintStream(os);
    ps.print(toAscii(code2)); //--> here it freezes
    System.out.println("cashopen ");//--> not even arrives here
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //--> the exception is not being catched
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Can't open the cashdrawer");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
    ps.close();}
}
}

public StringBuilder toAscii( String hex ){
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
       String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
       output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
     }
    return output;
}
```

Other exceptions are working. Any idea is welcome. I'm using Eclipse, Windows x64, Java se 8 121

**EDIT**

Tested in another computer Win7 x32, Java se 8 121 x32, and it's all fine. No idea what can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in another computer, working fine now. Something was wrong with Eclipse or Java in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Throws IOException
```

instead of the filenotfound

Comment: Not working, not throwing any error or exception. EDT just freezes.

Comment: println str see what it is doing

Comment: All it's fine till it arrives to the .print() method in  both cases.